# How can I use PowerShell to expand placeholders in a template string using values read from an INI file?

Tags: powershell, templates, ini, string-interpolation

**values.ini** looks like

```
[default]
A=1
B=2
C=3
```

**foo.txt** looks like

```
Now is the %A% for %a% %B% men to come to the %C% of their %c%
```

I want to use Powershell to search for all of the %x% values in **values.ini** and then replace every matching instance in **foo.txt** with the corresponding value, case insensitively; generating the following:

```
Now is the 1 for 1 2 men to come to the 3 of their 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming PowerShell version 3.0 or newer, you can use the `ConvertFrom-StringData` cmdlet to parse the key-value pair in your ini file, but you'll need to filter out the `[default]` directive:

```
# grab relevant lines from file
$KeyValPairs = Get-Content .\values.ini | Where {$_ -like "*=*" }

# join strings together as one big string
$KeyValPairString = $KeyValPairs -join [Environment]::NewLine

# create hashtable/dictionary from string with ConvertFrom-StringData
$Dictionary = $KeyValPairString |ConvertFrom-StringData
```

You can then use the `[regex]::Replace()` method to do a lookup against the dictionary for each match you want to replace:

```
Get-Content .\foo.txt |ForEach-Object { 
    [Regex]::Replace($_, '%(\p{L}+)%', {
        param($Match)

        # look term up in dictionary
        return $Dictionary[$Match.Groups[1].Value]
    }) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40427875/45375) with alternative approaches that also take the later requirement change of limiting values to a specific INI-file *section* into account (PSv2+, except for `Get-Content -Raw`; in PSv2, use `` (Get-Content ...) -join "`n" `` instead.)

**Using [`PsIni\Get-IniContent`](http://lipkau.github.io/PsIni/) and `[environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables()`**:

```
# Translate key-value pairs from section the section of interest
# into environment variables.
# After this command, the following environment variables are defined:
#     $env:A, with value 1 (cmd.exe equivalent: %A%)
#     $env:B, with value 2 (cmd.exe equivalent: %B%)
#     $env:C, with value 3 (cmd.exe equivalent: %C%)
$section = 'default'  # Specify the INI-file section of interest.
(Get-IniContent values.ini)[$section].GetEnumerator() | 
  ForEach-Object { Set-Item "env:$($_.Name)" -Value $_.Value }

# Read the template string as a whole from file foo.txt, and expand the
# environment-variable references in it, using the .NET framework.
# With the sample input, this yields
#  "Now is the 1 for 1 2 men to come to the 3 of their 3".
[environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables((Get-Content -Raw foo.txt))
```

The 3rd-party `Get-IniContent` cmdlet, which conveniently reads an INI file (`*.ini`) into a nested, ordered hashtable, can easily be installed with `Install-Module PsIni` from an elevated console (alternatively, add `-Scope CurrentUser`), if you have PS v5+ (or v3 or v4 with [PackageManagement](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51451) installed).

This solution takes advantage of the fact that the placeholders (e.g., `%a%`) look like `cmd.exe`-style environment-variable references.

Note the **assumptions and caveats**:

- All ini-file keys / placeholder names are legal environment-variable names.
- Preexisting variables may be overwritten, which can be problematic with names such as `PATH`.
- Cross-platform caveat: on Unix-like platforms, environment-variable references are *case-sensitive*, so the solution won't work the same there.

---

**Using custom INI-file parsing and `[environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables()`**:

If installing a module for INI-file parsing is not an option, the following solution uses a - rather complex - regular expression to extract the section of interest via the `-replace` operator.

```
$section = 'default'  # Specify the INI-file section of interest.
# Get all non-empty, non-comment lines from the section using a regex.
$sectLines = (Get-Content -Raw values.ini) -replace ('(?smn)\A.*?(^|\r\n)\[' + [regex]::Escape($section) + '\]\r\n(?<sectLines>.*?)(\r\n\[.*|\Z)'), '${sectLines}' -split "`r`n" -notmatch '(^;|^\s*$)'
# Define the key-value pairs as environment variables.
$sectlines | ForEach-Object { $tokens = $_ -split '=', 2; Set-Item "env:$($tokens[0].Trim())" -Value $tokens[1].Trim() }

# Read the template string as a whole, and expand the environment-variable 
# references in it, as before. 
[environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables((Get-Content -Raw foo.txt))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler solution using this [INI script](http://lipkau.github.io/PsIni/) called **Get-IniContent**.

```
#read from Setup.ini
$INI = Get-IniContent .\Setup.ini
$sec="setup"

#REPLACE VARIABLES
foreach($c in Get-ChildItem -Path .\Application  -Recurse -Filter *.config)
{
  Write-Output $c.FullName
  Write-Output $c.DirectoryName

  $configFile = Get-Content $c.FullName -Raw
  foreach($v in $INI[$sec].Keys)
  {
    $k = '%'+$v+'%'
    $match = [regex]::IsMatch($configFile, $k)
    if($match)
    {
      $configFile = $configFile -ireplace [regex]::Escape($k), $INI[$sec][$v]
    }
  }
  Set-Content $c.FullName -Value $configFile 
}
```

Comment: The `PsIni` module, also available from the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PsIni) via `Install-Module`, is a great find, but please don't post a self-answer that (a) quietly extends the scope of you original question (proper INI-parsing limited to a  _specific section_), (b) contains quite a bit of additional code unrelated to your specific question (at least not without explanation), (c) uses filenames and other identifiers that differ from the ones in your question.

Comment: And while the use of `Get-IniContent` is indeed a helpful simplification, the code that replaces the placeholders in the template string is both more verbose and less efficient than the technique in Mathias' answer.